# Is the following CFG ambiguous?

Tags: formal-languages, context-free, formal-grammars

I was given the following CFG :

$S \rightarrow A\ |\ B$

$A\rightarrow aAa\ |\ abAb\ |\ bAc\ |\ aca\ |\ abcb\ |\ bcc$

$B \rightarrow bBa\ |\ aBb\ |\ babBc\ |\ bca\ |\ acb\ |\ babcc$

And I have to show if it is ambiguous by giving two leftmost derivations for the same word.

I am pretty sure that there are two leftmost derivations but I can not find them.

I do not need the solution, just a tip where to start with would be enough.

Comment: It seems this grammar is unambiguous after all.

Comment: I figured that out as well.
I think I should start with A → abAb and end with bcc and start B → with aBb and end with babcc

Answer (score -1):

Is unambiguous because there is no string of rule A which is a string or substring of B. And viceversa.

Comment: But why is that true? You have to explain.

Comment: This is not enough to justify that the grammar is unambiguous. There could be more than one way to build an A using only A rules.